# System.Drawing.Image to Emgu.CV.Mat

Tags: c#, emgucv

As titled. I am having a problem of converting System.Drawing.Image to Emgu.CV.Mat
I tried to covert it from Drawing.Image to CV.Image but keep having Exceptions.

Is there any other solution available? Any help render is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A OpenCV or EmguCV IMage has a Mat header in it. The trick I found was to get the System.Drawing.Image into a Image<>. If you are having trouble with exceptions be sure you are compiling for x64 if you are using EmguCV 3.1.

Here is a simple method to get a Mat object:

```
private Mat GetMatFromSDImage(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
    int stride = 0;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);

    System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat pf = bmp.PixelFormat;
    if (pf == System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    {
        stride = bmp.Width * 4;
    }
    else
    {
        stride = bmp.Width * 3;
    }

    Image<Bgra, byte> cvImage = new Image<Bgra, byte>(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, stride, (IntPtr)bmpData.Scan0);

    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return cvImage.Mat;
}
```

Hope this helps!
Doug

Comment: I have mark the answer but due to the reputation, i think stackoverflow does not publicly display

Comment: Could be. My reputation is not very high. Thanks for trying.